# I am struggling to understand the question of user Quang Thinh Ha, can you help me figure it out?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[According to this question,](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66687/why-is-discrimination-based-on-citizenship-allowed-in-phd-funding-in-the-uk)
UK is not providing funding for international student, which is malicious and not true, all my advisory team, mentor and two co-mentors, all 3 of them, plus head of department and her husband, and other academic stuff in 50%, they finished PhD (with scholarship) inUK, and they are all from ASIA!!! country very close to Vietnam, I cannot believe in his words. Is he playing racist card? or political situation changed?

Comment: I think your perspective is skewed, as the answers point out, most Research Council funding is limited to UK/EU students and most schools charge higher international fees.

Comment: and why most asian students get scholarship and study in UK? @StrongBad

Comment: @SSimon No, they don't.  Most students from Asia study in Asia.  Most who go internationally do not go to the UK. It's a big world out there.

Comment: @SSimon About 4,427,000,000 people live in Asia. And you're trying to pass a few dozen students off as "most"?

Comment: @jakebeal maybe I have only anecdotal evidence,

Comment: @djechlin I am trying to focus myself on people from SAE that are now on tenured positions at universities. if you look that group of people, 80%  finished PhD abroad, more then 50% in UK

Comment: @SSimon isn't it "racist" of you to assume they get tenure because of their race and not because they deserve it? The logic here, I don't follow it.

Comment: but they are Asians, Asians get tenure in Asian countries, where they are citizens, @djechlin

Comment: " if you look that group of people, 80% finished PhD abroad, more then 50% in UK" -- **citation needed**

Comment: @YemonChoi that is information from website of my university!!!!

Answer (score 5):

The question says:

> Most of the funding I applied for were strictly 'UK/EU citizens only', and it is rare to have full funding for international students. I have applied to a lot of places, and received a lot of responses in the form of "... you are a good match, but I don't have funding for overseas students...".

then goes on to ask why it is considered acceptable to limit some sources of PhD funding to its own or EU citizens.

The OP never claims that "UK is not providing funding for international student" as you seem to believe, so the fact that some international students complete funded PhDs in the UK does not contradict any claims in the question. The OP says only that in his experience, there is less funding available to applicants who are not UK/EU citizens.

If you have some reliable (not anecdotal) data showing that the ratio of available funding to PhD applicants is identical for UK/EU students and non-UK/EU students, by all means, please provide that data. I suspect that you do not.

Comment: I just have a data of number of SEA students receiving PhD scholarships.

Comment: @SSimon Well, clearly that doesn't contradict that some sources of funding are limited to UK/EU citizens, and that general availability of funding for UK/EU citizens is greater.

Comment: that is not a problem, it is common sence, problem is that he stays there are not so many.

Comment: @SSimon You say you have data, but then above you admit that perhaps you only have anecdotes.

Comment: where is that? @YemonChoi

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out the problem that you do not know how many international students applied for these positions received by your colleagues who were rejected. You also have not clarified whether your colleagues are not funded through the university and I suspect you don't have a clue.

I *strongly* encourage you to not accuse someone of "playing the race card" when you admit you do not understand the situation at all.

Comment: what you mean I dont know?

Comment: @SSimon can you answer the question, how many international students applied for those positions and were rejected?

Comment: phD positions or PhD scholarships?

Comment: @SSimon both? either? Do you know anything about either?

Comment: only PhD scholarships @djecnlin